# Python Email Notification Not Sending

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, smtp

This code is supposed to send an email to a specified address and when I hard code the "TEXT" & "SUBJECT" it seems to send fine but when I create it as a function and call it it never sends the email and never prints the "Notification Sent" message. What am I missing?

Tried hard coding the TEXT and SUBJECT and it sends fine! NOTE: YOU MUST ENABLE LESS SECURE APPS WHEN USING GMAIL!

```
import smtplib

class email_thing:

    def email_notification(self,SUBJECT,TEXT):

        TO = 'email@example.com'
        self.SUBJECT = SUBJECT
        self.TEXT = TEXT
        gmail_sender = 'email@example.com'
        gmail_passwd = 'examplepassword'
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

        return self.SUBJECT
        return self.TEXT

        BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % TO,
                            'From: %s' % gmail_sender,
                            'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT,
                            '',TEXT])
        try:
            server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
            print ('Notification Sent!')
        except:
           print ('error sending mail')

        server.quit()

test_send = email_thing()
test_send.email_notification(SUBJECT ='Test Email',TEXT = 'This is a test from python!')
```

Comment: see `return` in `email_notification()`. `return` exits method at once so rest of code is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
    return self.SUBJECT
    return self.TEXT
```

`return` exits method at once so code after `return` is never executed.